# why android Actionbar backbutton shows highlighted selected state without pressing it

Tags: android

I am using

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(actionView, actionBarLayoutParam);
```

so the problem is my back button always shows highlighted box around it like it is pressed, but i did not pressed the button